# Authorize attribute failing to block requests in ASP.Net Core 3.0 Web API

Tags: c#, authentication, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working through trying to get cookie-based authentication working with an ASP.Net Core 3.0 Web Api project.

At the moment, my ConfigureServices looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader());
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(options => 
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
            })
            .AddCookie("Cookies", options => 
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "auth_cookie";
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
                {
                    OnRedirectToLogin = redirectContext =>
                    {
                        redirectContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });

        services.AddAuthorization();

        services.AddControllers();
    }
```

And my Configure method looks like:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization();
        });
    }
```

I applied the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Authorize] attribute to the default generated WeatherForecastController, and browsed to the relevant page. I was expecting to receive a failure, because there was no cookie on my request, however the page loads without issue.

Inspecting the debug logs, I can see the following:

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host: Debug: Hosting started
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44376/weatherforecast  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware: Debug: Wildcard detected, all requests with hosts will be allowed.
***Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler: Debug: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was not authenticated.***
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher: Debug: 1 candidate(s) found for the request path '/weatherforecast'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher: Debug: Endpoint 'NotesApp.WebApi.Controllers.WeatherForecastController.Get (NotesApp.WebApi)' with route pattern 'WeatherForecast' is valid for the request path '/weatherforecast'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware: Debug: Request matched endpoint 'NotesApp.WebApi.Controllers.WeatherForecastController.Get (NotesApp.WebApi)'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Information: Executing endpoint 'NotesApp.WebApi.Controllers.WeatherForecastController.Get (NotesApp.WebApi)'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelBinderFactory: Debug: Registered model binder providers, in the following order: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BinderTypeModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ServicesModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BodyModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.HeaderModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.FloatingPointTypeModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.EnumTypeModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.SimpleTypeModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.CancellationTokenModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ByteArrayModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.FormFileModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.FormCollectionModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.KeyValuePairModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.DictionaryModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ArrayModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.CollectionModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ComplexTypeModelBinderProvider
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Route matched with {action = "Get", controller = "WeatherForecast"}. Executing controller action with signature System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[NotesApp.WebApi.WeatherForecast] Get() on controller NotesApp.WebApi.Controllers.WeatherForecastController (NotesApp.WebApi).
***Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Debug: Execution plan of authorization filters (in the following order): None***
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Debug: Execution plan of resource filters (in the following order): None
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Debug: Execution plan of action filters (in the following order): Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.UnsupportedContentTypeFilter (Order: -3000), Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ModelStateInvalidFilter (Order: -2000)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Debug: Execution plan of exception filters (in the following order): None
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Debug: Execution plan of result filters (in the following order): Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ClientErrorResultFilter (Order: -2000)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Debug: Executing controller factory for controller NotesApp.WebApi.Controllers.WeatherForecastController (NotesApp.WebApi)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Debug: Executed controller factory for controller NotesApp.WebApi.Controllers.WeatherForecastController (NotesApp.WebApi)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultOutputFormatterSelector: Debug: List of registered output formatters, in the following order: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.HttpNoContentOutputFormatter, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.StringOutputFormatter, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.StreamOutputFormatter, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultOutputFormatterSelector: Debug: No information found on request to perform content negotiation.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultOutputFormatterSelector: Debug: Attempting to select an output formatter without using a content type as no explicit content types were specified for the response.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultOutputFormatterSelector: Debug: Attempting to select the first formatter in the output formatters list which can write the result.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultOutputFormatterSelector: Debug: Selected output formatter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter' and content type 'application/json' to write the response.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor: Information: Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type 'NotesApp.WebApi.WeatherForecast[]'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executed action NotesApp.WebApi.Controllers.WeatherForecastController.Get (NotesApp.WebApi) in 65.9499ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Information: Executed endpoint 'NotesApp.WebApi.Controllers.WeatherForecastController.Get (NotesApp.WebApi)'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished in 182.95000000000002ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Note the two lines I have starred - the first correct identifies that we were not authenticated for the cookies scheme. The second however indicates there are no Authorization filters on the controller, which is puzzling, because there are. This is presumably why the request is being allowed.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
[Authorize]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        var rng = new Random();
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Can anyone please shed any light on why the Authorize attribute is not being detected and actioned by the runtime?

I don't care so much at this point about the mechanics of the cookie, I just want the controller to be correctly blocked.

Many thanks

Answer (score 6):

By disabling the endpoint routing you are actually falling back to 2.x routing. In order to solve the problem you should make sure you use the [correct order](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/#order) of building the pipeline:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

By analysing the log file of another project which was working, I realised that the [Authorize] attribute adds an AuthorizeFilter from the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter namespace. Thus, the app must be configured to use Mvc for it the attribute to be detected and work properly.

Adding the following into ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
```

and the following into Configure:

```
app.UseMvc();
```

got it working.

Not exactly "obvious", but there you go.